# one-to-many relationship doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create one-to-many relationship with 2 models, `User` and `Role`. So, I would like that one `User` can only have one role, and the `Role` can be assigned to more than `User`.  I tried to follow the offical tutorial on https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many, and ended up with this:

```
class User extends Model 
{
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin\Role');
    }
}

class Role extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'roles';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Admin\User');
    }

}
```

Based on that link, I think the `Role` is the same thing as the `Post`, one `Role` can be assigned to many `User`. However, this doesn't quite work, here is how I tried to access the role name for a specific `User`

```
$role_first = $user->role; // Eloquent\Collection
$role_second = $user->role(); // Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany

$role_first->role_title // 'Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$role_title'
$role_second->role_title // exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::$role_title'
```

What is exactly wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `User` class

```
public function role()
{
    // not $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin\Role');
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Admin\Role');
}
```

Because you want a `oneToMany` not `manyToMany` relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the relation

- **A User hasOne Role**
- **A Role belongsToMany Users**

so, in this condition

```
class User extends Model 
{
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Admin\Role');
    }
}
class Role extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'roles';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin\User');
    }
}
```

and must check your user_id foreign constraint be 'unsigned' in your role migration table.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Please give it a try

```
class User extends Model 
{
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(App\Admin\Role::class);
    }
}

// user belongs to one role
class Role extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'roles';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Admin\User::class);
    }

}
```

Comment: You've created one-to-one relation here (hasOne and belongsTo) which is incorrect. Many users can have same role which is one-to-many relation.

Answer (score 0):

User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable{

  public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Admin\Role');
  }
   }
```

Role Model

```
    class Role extends Model{

     public function users(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\Admin\User');
     }
      }
```

The user can have only one role, and the role can be assigned to many users.